# Pinning songs on Google Music

Tags: google-play-music

Google Music allows me to 'pin' songs in Android so that I can listen to them while offline.  Is it possible to do this on a computer as well?

All of my music is stored on my home PC, and now I can listen to it on Google Music, but I would like to be able to download songs from the cloud to my work laptop so that I can share them on [outloud.fm](http://outloud.fm/).

I've got a feeling this feature doesn't exist, but I might just be overlooking it.  Is this possible?  Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 1):

Offline playback is only supported on Android devices at present. This option is not available for playback via your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a Virtual Machine running Android, and do it from there.
A little Google-fu found me [this article](http://geeknizer.com/how-to-run-google-android-in-virtualbox-vmware-on-netbooks/). Note that I have not actually tried this (though I probably will once I get home from work).